# Func and Action

Tags: c#

I have got two generic methods to call against a service. Depending on call, some methods return an object (passed in params), some don't (void). Can this be further improved? I have got to this point after refactoring a lot and removing anything which was repeated.

```
private static TResponse ServiceCall<TObjectToPass, TResponse>(
    Func<TObjectToPass, TResponse> func, 
    TObjectToPass obj)
{
    var temp = ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback;
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
        (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;

    var r = func(obj);

    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = temp;

    return r;
}

private static void ServiceCall<TObjectToPass>(
    Action<TObjectToPass> func, 
    TObjectToPass obj)
{
    var temp = ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback;
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
        (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;

    func(obj);

    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = temp;
}
```

Comment: Is the intent of your `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` delegate to *always* validate certificates regardless of the certificate?  That's not really what you're doing there.

Comment: You don't really need to pass in obj separately, as it can just be part of the action/func that gets injected.

Comment: @CodingGorilla yes. Regardless, it needs to return `true`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Keep the reference to your callback, so you can remove it when it is no longer needed :

   ```
   // add this to the class
   private static readonly RemoteCertificateValidationCallback IgnoreValidation =
       (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;

   // inside your methods
   ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += IgnoreValidation;
   // do stuffs
   ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback -= IgnoreValidation;
   ```
2. Consider switch the order of your parameter. `TObjectToPass` is the key generic parameter in both method, yet its definition is unclear until the 2nd parameter is passed or unless you specify in `ServerCall<__HERE__>(...` or `ServerCall((___HERE x) => ...`. By keep it on the 2nd place, you penalize yourself by not taking advantage of intellisense :

   ```
   // compiler has no idea what is x
   ServiceCall(x => x

   // compiler is happy to tell you what x can do
   ServiceCall(new { A = 'a' }, x => Console.WriteLine(x.A
   ```

   ---

   ```
   private static TResponse ServiceCall<TObjectToPass, TResponse>(
   TObjectToPass obj,
   Func<TObjectToPass, TResponse> func)
   {
       ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += IgnoreValidation;
       var response = func(obj);
       ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback -= IgnoreValidation;

       return response;
   }

   private static void ServiceCall<TObjectToPass>(
       TObjectToPass obj,
       Action<TObjectToPass> action)
   {
       ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += IgnoreValidation;
       action(obj);
       ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback -= IgnoreValidation;
   }
   ```